# ionic app not finding providers in linked package

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ionic3

I have an ionic app and angular web app that both consume the same REST API. For initial development I had the api implementation code copied in both projects, but now I'd like to extract the api services into a linked npm package that both projects can use and import as a module. The package compiles fine but my Ionic app can't find the providers from the services module in the package.

My services package module looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { AuthenticationService } from "./authentication.service";
import { CognitoUtil, CognitoCallback, LoggedInCallback } from "./cognito.service";
import { DocumentsService } from "./documents.service";
import { TagService } from "./tag.service";
import { UsersService } from "./users.service";
import { AwsUtil } from "./aws.service";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ApiService,
    AuthenticationService,
    CognitoUtil,
    AwsUtil,
    DocumentsService,
    TagService,
    UsersService
  ],
  providers: [
    AwsUtil,
    CognitoUtil,
    ApiService,
    AuthenticationService,
    ApiService,
    DocumentsService,
    TagService
  ]
})
export class MyAppServicesModule {

}
```

The index.ts file for the package looks like this:

```
export { MyAppServicesModule } from './myapp-services.module';
```

My tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",   
    "module": "commonjs", 
    "declaration": true,  
    "outDir": "out",    
    "rootDir": "src",  
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "out"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "@myapp/services",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My App services",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^8.0.19",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.3",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^1.19.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2"
  }
}
```

After compiling the package I link the package

```
npm link
```

In my application code I create a link to my package

```
npm link @myapp/services
```

I then import the services module into my main app module

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    MyApp
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    MyAppServicesModule,
    LoginPageModule,
    DocumentsPageModule,
],
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
    MyApp
],
providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And in my login page I import the `AuthenticationService` and declare it in the constructor so it gets set by the dependency injector

```
import { AuthenticationService } from '@myapp/services'

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage  {

constructor (public navCtrl: NavController,
             public navParams: NavParams,
             public authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}
```

But I get the following error when trying to serve my app

```
typescript: src/pages/login/login.ts, line: 27
Cannot find name 'AuthenticationService'.

L26:  public navParams: NavParams,
L27:  public authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}
```

I also get the same error for all references to any of the providers from the services module. I've tried listing the services in the `exports` section of the services module as well but that didn't fix the issue.

My ionic version

```
Ionic Framework: 3.2.1
Ionic App Scripts: 1.3.7
Angular Core: 4.1.0
Angular Compiler CLI: 4.1.0
Node: 7.7.1
OS Platform: macOS Sierra
Navigator Platform: MacIntel
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.4
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For an Ionic app. Most of the stuff in @ngModule applies to Angular too:

**declarations**: Make components, directives and pipes available to module that don't come from another module. You don't put services here!

**imports**: Bring in other Angular modules your module will need. BrowserModule, HttpModule, IonicModule etc.

**entryComponents**: Things like pages

**providers**: Your services go here, also things like StatusBar, SplashScreen, Keyboard, ionic error handler...

Comment: Sure. And that is what I've done. My services are listed in the providers section of my package module, but when the application imports the package module, why doesn't the application see the services listed in the provider section of the imported module?